# Job that starts over when finished?

Tags: laravel, cron, queue, laravel-5

What I'm trying to create is a system that reads/parses data from over a dozen external websites.

As an example, let's say I want to create a system that parses Twitter posts on a specific user's profile page. I want to do this for over a dozen users.

Additionally, I want a separate job running for each of these users. So if there are 12 users, I need 12 jobs running.

When the job has finished (i.e. when it has parsed all of the user's posts on the page), I need the job to start over again (in order to parse any new posts).

So in the end, if there are 12 users, I should have 12 jobs that are constantly running which parse any new posts made by any of these 12 users.

As far as I know, there are two ways to do this. The first is to use [cron jobs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/scheduling), the second is to use Laravel's [queuing system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues).

**What is the best way to solve this? Cron jobs or queues? How would I implement it properly?**

With cron jobs, the two issues I can think of are that crons run based on time, not based on job completion, meaning that if a job is finished, it will have to wait until the cron job is called again (for example, every 5 minutes). The other issue is overlap. What if a job doesn't finish in time but the cron calls the job again?

This is what a simplified version of my current queue job implementation looks like, however, I noticed that my CPU usage jumps to between 75-90%:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Jobs\Job;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

use App\Models\Page;

class PageParser extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    protected $page;

    public function __construct(Page $page)
    {
        $this->page = $page;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        // Parsing done here, removed for simplicity

        $this->delete();
        dispatch(new PageParser($this->page));
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you actually looking for Twitter posts? If so, you should look at their streaming end points. Creating a never ending job would be quite easy by using a while loop based on the state of the connection

Comment: No, I'm not looking for Twitter posts. My example was a simplification of the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried this, but I would assume you could create a recursive job.

This recursive job would execute all code that it needed to, then, at the end of execution, it would create a new job and push it onto the queue - which would then start running as soon as the queue is ready for it.

If the job fails at any time, you would not have created a new job, so you wouldn't have any of the same user's job running concurrently. The failed job would simply be retried - and when successful, would create a new job.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination. Create a command like 'RetrieveDataCommand' or whatever. This command should push a job onto a queue for each user which will retrieve data for that user (and maybe a separate job for actually processing if required?). The job should take into account a '$from' parameter which is a time stamp if when the 'previous' command was ran. When it runs, it retrieves all data for all users for the time period $from to now().

You can then have a cron job run the command every 10 seconds or whatever. The $from can either be calculated by storing (in a cache/DB/something semi persistent) a time stamp of the current time as soon as the command is ran by the cron so the next command can look this up when it runs and then overwrite it for the next run. Or simply do now() minus the cron interval though that is less flexible.

You can then remove the self deletion and dispatch stuff from your job